# Windows Docker: Issues installing Visual C++ Redistributable in Windows Docker

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, dependencies, vcredist

Totally new to this..  Using .net 6.0.

trying to install a vc_redist.x64 into windows docker to run a windows exe with command line interface.  Searching around online came up with this to add to docker  file, but the redist isn't installed (event though build output shows that `RUN vc_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log vc_redist.log` line executed without errors, nor can I run the exe.  On docker image I cant find the dlls that would be associated with vc_redist.  What am I doing wrong?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN vc_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log vc_redist.log    

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Directory/Project1.csproj", "Project1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Directory/Project1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Directory"
RUN dotnet build "Project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project1.dll"]
```

Answer (score 8):

I found I was able to install this onto a docker image with the following code:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; `
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe" -OutFile "vc_redist.x64.exe"; `
    Start-Process -filepath C:\vc_redist.x64.exe -ArgumentList "/install", "/passive", "/norestart" -Passthru | Wait-Process; `
    Remove-Item -Force vc_redist.x64.exe;
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/15